# how to configure node-oracledb in heroku app

Tags: node.js, oracle, heroku, node-oracledb, oracle19c

I am new to heroku, getting error while trying to connecting to oracle cloud DB from my node-express App in heroku. I am able to connect from my local machine but not from heroku. Need help in config and client setup. I am not sure how we place tnsnames,sqlnet,wallet files.

oracle : 19C ~ connecting using oracle wallet

Local machine config:

wallet location: $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/wallet

tnsnames:$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

sqlnet:$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

Oracle NPM : oracledb: 5.0.0

code:

```
 const oracle = require('oracledb');
 const connection = await oracle.getConnection({
                    user:  'XXX',
                    password: 'XXX',
                    connectString: 'XXX' });
```

getting below error while trying to access oracle from heroku :

Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig. If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

Any help is appreciated..!!

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed 64 bit client from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html  ???

Comment: And if you use Instant Client, then _never_ set ORACLE_HOME.  See the [node-oracledb doc on  Initializing Node-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#initnodeoracledb).

Comment: Yes but how to do it in Heroku ?, Any steps to do it.? For node-oracledb

Comment: Google?  Search StackOverflow?  There are answers to similar questions here.

Comment: [node-oracledb 6.0](https://medium.com/@sharad-chandran/usher-in-a-new-era-with-the-node-oracledb-6-0-pure-javascript-thin-driver-e10e2af693b2) can be used without Instant Client.